# Searching in yahoo using java

Tags: java, search

Recently I wrote a program to search yahoo with a given string.

The string I passed to my program is
`http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?site="+URLEncoder.encode(sitename)+"&appid=YahooDemo&query="+URLEncoder.encode(query)+"&results=20&start="+pagec+"&output=json`.

Parameters:

- `sitename` for getting results for a particular site
- `query` for string that to be searched in yahoo server.

But I'm getting the following error when I execute this program:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Message": ["The service has been shut down. For further details, please see the Deprecated Services blog post http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes"],
        "Title": "The following errors were detected:"
    }
}
```

What is the cause for getting this error?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the service has been shut down?

Comment: thanks for your replay.so,how can i solve this problem..??

Comment: [read this great article](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes)

Comment: I just rollbacked it, because you turned the question upside down. It was a complete different question. You can ask another question, but do not turn an existing question into a complete different question. This is confusing for everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service has been shut down [since April 2011](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/webSearch.html). You can use [Yahoo! Search BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) instead, but you've to pay for it.

You may consider switching to [Google Custom Search](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) which is free up to 100 queries per day, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're OK and they just shut down the service. Have you read the [blog entry](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes/) they sent you back?