# Error while reading Yahoo! Answers website

Tags: java, web-scraping, yahoo

I want to search some of my queries from a file (a.txt) and search them in Yahoo! Answers site and, finally write the retrieved results in another file (b.txt)

My code is as follows:

```
public static void run() throws IOException {
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("XX.XX.XX.XX", 8080));
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("a.txt")));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    int len = lnr.getLineNumber();
    lnr.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i++) {
        String ll = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("a.txt")).get(i);
        String l = URLEncoder.encode(ll, "UTF-8");
        String surl = "https://answers.yahoo.com/search/search_result?p=" + l + "&sort=rel";
        System.out.println("Search URL: " + surl);
        URL url = new URL(surl);
        InputStream in = url.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("b.txt"), true));
            pw.println(line);
            pw.close();
        }
        rd.close();
    }
```

But, I am getting error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=How+a+13+year+old+boy+can+lose+weight%3F&sort=rel
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at Yahoo.run(Yahoo.java:117)
at Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

But when I am using the search string in browser url, the desired result is being shown in the Yahoo! site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in the code. Read this question : 
[Searching in yahoo using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716398/searching-in-yahoo-using-java)

You will have to use  [BOSS API](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/overview.html) to do your searching from now on. See this [example](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_java) and start off from there. You have to change the code which is doing the connection and fetching from yahoo.All the best.

Comment: Is it not working only for Yahoo! search? Using this code, I can access other sites still now. For using BOSS APIs, what are the necessary jar files as per your [example](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_java)?